# Modification in wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am extremely new in wordpress, have installed it today. I am working on a task to customize main page in wordpress. I face a problem that I want to insert logo into theme which I am unable to do that
Here is the code

```
<div class="site-logo">

<--! Here I want to add my logo>
                </div>
```

I have use theme logo plugin to insert that but it shows all the code on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is dependent on how you wish to incorporate the image into your theme.

If the image is an asset of the theme itself, meaning the files are located in the theme package, you can include the file using `get_template_directory_uri()`.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg">
```

WP also has a Custom Headers feature that will give you the ability to manage a header image from the WP Admin  https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers

**functions.php**

```
$args = array(
  'width'         => 980,
  'height'        => 60,
  'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

**In your theme**

```
<img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php echo( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."logo.jpg";?>" alt="logo">
```

Use the above code.
`get_template_directory_uri()` give you the path of your current theme.
[Refer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

Answer (score 1):

if your logo is in "images" folder in root directory (not in your WP theme:

```
/images/logo.jpg
```

If your logo is in images folder of WP Theme:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/logo.jpg
```

if your logo is not in "images" folder, then delete the reference for images folder.